# Add left space/margin/padding in VS Code editor window between line numbers and code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would love to have some space between the line numbers and the first intendation/code in the VS Code editor window:

[image]

I just want to indent the code in the editor without actually adding whitespace in the code.

I tried `"editor.glyphMargin"`, but this will only increase the space on the left of the line numbers, not between the line numbers and the code.

I'm also aware of the "Centered Layout" view, but this also decreases the width of e. g. the tabs for the file selection.

Is there a setting I'm missing or do I need a plugin/custom CSS?

Comment: Here is the ticket about making editor.lineDecorationsWidth as official setting - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93887 (we have to collect 20 upvotes)

Comment: Here is the ticket about editor.contentLeftPadding as official setting. This setting not only resolve visual but also usability issue. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135114 (20 or more upvotes needed)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try this --

`"editor.lineDecorationsWidth": 25,`

This increases the space on the right side of the numbers. I haven't seen anything that increases the padding on the other side of the gutter nearest your code.

**Opinion** --
Ideally, there would be a `editor.padding.left` like there is a `editor.padding.top`, but I haven't seen this yet.

Comment: I would also love to have paddings for all sides, but `lineDecorationsWidth` has to do it for now. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the ticket about making editor.lineDecorationsWidth as official setting - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93887 (we have to collect 20 upvotes)

Comment: This doesn't work in 2021, but good news is the issue @kanlukasz gave in the above comment is now passed 60 upvotes and already in their backlog.

Comment: Here is the ticket about editor.contentLeftPadding as official setting. This setting not only resolve visual but also usability issue. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135114 (20 or more upvotes needed)

Comment: 2023 dec: this works! my csv file I was checking for bugs had enormous gap between line number and actual numbers, but I realized they weren't spaces. I set   `"editor.lineDecorationsWidth" : 0` in settings.json and it fixed the issue. default setting seems to be 25 which is 25 too many imo. Settings file still said "unknown setting" but it works.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [hidden](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93887) setting called `editor.lineDecorationsWidth`, that you can use like `"editor.lineDecorationsWidth": 100` in a [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson). It doesn't do *exactly* what's being looked for here since it's not actually controlling the padding between the gutter and the editor- the line decoration space is where things like code folding handles go- but for some use-cases, it might be close enough.

For the ideal case, there's an open issue ticket to add a setting for left padding that would essentially do what `editor.padding.bottom` and `editor.padding.top` do- just for the left side of the editor: [Add `editor.contentLeftPadding to add padding between the editorGutter and editor. #135114](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135114). It's currently in the backlog. Give it a thumbs up to show support for it, and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments like "+1" / "bump".