# How can I add padding to VS Code's code editor panel

Tags: visual-studio-code

By default the gutter and the code editor have white backgrounds and you can't tell that there is no space between the two. In my color scheme the gutter is gray (trying to match IntelliJ-based IDE) and as you can see the first column of the code is basically touching the guter.

What I am trying to do is to add some kind of space in between or some left-padding to the code editor.

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

This is what it looks like:
[image: VS Code code editor]

This is what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: You can check the answer of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/59031656/9346979

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that is not it. The instruction basically makes line gutter wider, it works for the other answered question because they have the gutter and the code editor in the same color, in my case it just makes the gutter wider, the code will be further for line number but still 0-pixel from the gray gutter. See: https://prnt.sc/u9z0ga

Comment: Here is the ticket about editor.contentLeftPadding as official setting. This setting will not only resolve visual but also usability issue. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135114 (upvotes on the feature request are highly appreciated.)