# Why do certain fonts' characters get cropped off the left margin of the editor panel in VS Code and how can it be fixed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am a teacher who teaches kids coding through video conferencing. Sometimes, I use unique and interesting fonts to induce their concentration(I use vscode). However, some fonts have an issue where the left side is cut off when starting a new line. How can I solve this problem? Is there a way to allocate space when starting a new line?

[image]

I've searching and try everything as possible as I can but problem is not solved.

Comment: ooh bummer. I see `editor.padding.bottom` and `editor.padding.top` settings, but none for left and right. Anyhow, please add steps to reproduce this (what font? what font settings?).

Comment: All the calligraphy-fonts make this issues. I change my font for lesson but I still want to solve it! :(

Comment: There is an issue about adding left padding, and someone seems to have a workaround. I haven't tried: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135114#issuecomment-944639512

Comment: related to the left padding issue ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59031656/11107541