How to enable "unstable" settings?
I found out that there are "unstable" settings for TS in VS code, and I would need to enable this one:
{"typescript.unstable": {"organizeImportsIgnoreCase": true,}}

But no matter where I try to add it in settings.json, it remains grey with the label
"Unknown Configuration Setting"
I have TS version 5.5.4, anything specific I need to do to activate unstable settings?

This is more related to the version of VS Code than to the version of TypeScript.

Where did you find about this setting?

found about the setting in the official TS v5 website: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html
I have the latest VS Code version installed

The fact that it's greyed out and that VS Code says the setting is unknown doesn't necessarily mean it's not taking effect. There are some "hidden" settings (that's not an official term. It's just how I describe it) that are just like that. Ex. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77283203/11107541. The business logic for a setting is implemented by the extension's code, and the declaration of the setting and what sorts of values it takes on goes in an extension manifest. I'm pretty sure this is just what happens when a setting isn't declared in the manifest, as seems to be the case here.

unfortunately I tried to see if the setting was working regardless of it being greyed out, but it doesn't, that is why I thought there might be a setting to enable these "unstable" settings in VsCode
